# Actionscript 3.0 Popup

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to get a popup message to display for 1 second when the right answer is selected. All this pop up says is "Right Answer". I have made a function that makes the popup visible and I have put setTimeout in an if state (this if statement is if the right answer is selected). My code below and I would appreciate any help at all!

This is my function for the display

```
//------Popup--------// 

right_ans.alpha = 0; //set to zero so message wont be displayed throughout game

//--------Popup function-------// 

function DisplayAnswer(event:MouseEvent):void{

right_ans.alpha = 5;

}
```

This is the if statement with the setTimeout

```
if(event.target == pig) //object
        {
            currentQuestion++;
            score = score + 5; 
            Score_txt.text = (score).toString(); 
            setTimeout(DisplayAnswer, 1000);



        }
```

Comment: set alpha to 0.5 not 5 , thos values was in the AS2 , now the alpha's value are between 0 to 1

Answer (score 0):

Set alpha to 1, not 5.  It accepts values from 0 to 1, being 0% to 100% opacity.

Comment: Oh ok, I changed that but the popup still isnt appearing. Thanks for the tip though :)

Comment: Your `DisplayAnswer` function is set up as if it were a click listener, but it's being called directly from `setTimeout`.  Try removing the `event:MouseEvent` from the function header.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if(event.target == pig) //object
    {
        currentQuestion++;
        score = score + 5; 
        Score_txt.text = (score).toString(); 
        setTimeout(DisplayAnswer, 1000);



    }
//------Popup--------// 

right_ans.alpha = 0; //set to zero so message wont be displayed throughout game

//--------Popup function-------// 

function DisplayAnswer():void{

    right_ans.alpha = 0.5;
    setTimeout(removeAnswer, 1000);

}

function removeAnswer():void{

    right_ans.alpha = 0.0;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the message appears now! But it wont go away after a second. Thanks so much :)

Comment: dont understand your question ?? you want it to diseapere after a seconde??

Comment: Ya I want it to disappear after a second but it wont. The message stays on screen

Comment: So approve the answer :D

Comment: I cant because my reputation isn't high enough!

Comment: ok man good coding , try to work with the tweens class , it help you a lot to animate object in scene, for example for this popup message you can animate it with the tween object, this give you a loot of things you can do like wait for the alpha animation to complete and the run another animation to fadeOut the message , google this( tween for as3 ) and good luck :)